# SQL TRANSACCIONES

Tags: sql, tsql, transacciones

Una consulta, tengo un procedimiento con manejo de transacciones, en la cual debe ejecutarse varios INSERT, como hago para saber en que INSERT fallo el procedimiento  de tal manera que pueda mostrar en el mensaje del `RAISERROR` algo como "error al insertar el documento XXXXXXXXX en el DIARIO"

He obviado la declaración de variables, etc, etc. con el fin de graficar lo que se pretendo lograr.

```
ALTER procedure PROCESA_FACTURA
(@PROVEEDOR VARCHAR(20),
 @DOCUMENTO VARCHAR(50),
 @TIPO VARCHAR(3))
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET LANGUAGE SPANISH;   

    BEGIN TRANSACTION 

    BEGIN TRY

        -- ASIENTO_DE_DIARIO
        INSERT INTO ASIENTO_DE_DIARIO
        (ASIENTO,PAQUETE,TIPO_ASIENTO,FECHA,CONTABILIDAD,ORIGEN,CLASE_ASIENTO,
            TOTAL_DEBITO_LOC,TOTAL_DEBITO_DOL,TOTAL_CREDITO_LOC,TOTAL_CREDITO_DOL,
            ULTIMO_USUARIO,FECHA_ULT_MODIF,MARCADO,NOTAS,TOTAL_CONTROL_LOC,TOTAL_CONTROL_DOL,
            USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION,DEPENDENCIA)
        SELECT 
        @ASIENTO, @PAQUETE, @TIPO_ASIENTO, @FECHA, @CONTABILIDAD, @ORIGEN, @CLASE_ASIENTO,
        @TOTAL_DEBITO_LOC, @TOTAL_DEBITO_DOL, @TOTAL_CREDITO_LOC, @TOTAL_CREDITO_DOL,
        @ULTIMO_USUARIO, @FECHA_ULT_MODIF, @MARCADO, @NOTAS_TEMP, @TOTAL_CONTROL_LOC, @TOTAL_CONTROL_DOL,
        @USUARIO_CREACION, @FECHA_CREACION, @DEPENDENCIA;


        -- DIARIO
        INSERT INTO DIARIO
        (ASIENTO,CONSECUTIVO,NIT,CENTRO_COSTO,CUENTA_CONTABLE,FUENTE,REFERENCIA,
            DEBITO_LOCAL,DEBITO_DOLAR,CREDITO_LOCAL,CREDITO_DOLAR,DEBITO_UNIDADES,CREDITO_UNIDADES,
            TIPO_CAMBIO,BASE_LOCAL,BASE_DOLAR,PROYECTO,FASE,PROCESO_REBATE)
        SELECT
        @ASIENTO,@CONSECUTIVO,@NIT,@CENTRO_COSTO,@CUENTA_CONTABLE,@FUENTE,@REFERENCIA,
        @DEBITO_LOCAL,@DEBITO_DOLAR,@CREDITO_LOCAL,@CREDITO_DOLAR,@DEBITO_UNIDADES,@CREDITO_UNIDADES,
        @TIPO_CAMBIO,@BASE_LOCAL,@BASE_DOLAR,@PROYECTO,@FASE,@PROCESO_REBATE;

        -- DIARIO2
        INSERT INTO DIARIO2
        (ASIENTO,CONSECUTIVO,NIT,CENTRO_COSTO,CUENTA_CONTABLE,FUENTE,REFERENCIA,
            DEBITO_LOCAL,DEBITO_DOLAR,CREDITO_LOCAL,CREDITO_DOLAR,DEBITO_UNIDADES,CREDITO_UNIDADES,
            TIPO_CAMBIO,BASE_LOCAL,BASE_DOLAR,PROYECTO,FASE,PROCESO_REBATE)
        SELECT
        @ASIENTO,@CONSECUTIVO,@NIT,@CENTRO_COSTO,@CUENTA_CONTABLE,@FUENTE,@REFERENCIA,
        @DEBITO_LOCAL,@DEBITO_DOLAR,@CREDITO_LOCAL,@CREDITO_DOLAR,@DEBITO_UNIDADES,@CREDITO_UNIDADES,
        @TIPO_CAMBIO,@BASE_LOCAL,@BASE_DOLAR,@PROYECTO,@FASE,@PROCESO_REBATE;


        -- MAYOR
        INSERT INTO MAYOR
        (ASIENTO,CONSECUTIVO,NIT,CENTRO_COSTO,CUENTA_CONTABLE,FUENTE,REFERENCIA,
            DEBITO_LOCAL,DEBITO_DOLAR,CREDITO_LOCAL,CREDITO_DOLAR,DEBITO_UNIDADES,CREDITO_UNIDADES,
            TIPO_CAMBIO,BASE_LOCAL,BASE_DOLAR,PROYECTO,FASE,PROCESO_REBATE)
        SELECT
        @ASIENTO,@CONSECUTIVO,@NIT,@CENTRO_COSTO,@CUENTA_CONTABLE,@FUENTE,@REFERENCIA,
        @DEBITO_LOCAL,@DEBITO_DOLAR,@CREDITO_LOCAL,@CREDITO_DOLAR,@DEBITO_UNIDADES,@CREDITO_UNIDADES,
        @TIPO_CAMBIO,@BASE_LOCAL,@BASE_DOLAR,@PROYECTO,@FASE,@PROCESO_REBATE;
        --END


        -- GRABA BITACORA
        INSERT INTO BITACORA
            (TIPO_CARGA,PROVEEDOR,FECHA_DOCUMENTO,TIPO_DOCUMENTO,DOCUMENTO,CONDICION_PAGO,SUBTOTAL,IMPUESTO,
             MONTO,MONEDA,TIPO_CAMB_DOCUM,TIPO_CAMB_TVTA,TIPO_CAMB_TCOM,MONTO_RETENCION,MONTO_DETRACCION,FECHA_PROCESO)
            SELECT
            'CARGA_XML',@PROVEEDOR,@FECHA_DOCUMENTO,@TIPO,@DOCUMENTO,@CONDICION_PAGO,@SUBTOTAL,@IMPUESTO1,
            @MONTO,@MONEDA,@TVTA,@TVTA,@TCOM,@MONTO_RETENCION, @MONTO_DETRACCION,GETDATE();

        COMMIT TRANSACTION 

    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH

        SET @strMsg = 'CARGA_XML_PROVEEDORES.   Se ha producido un error!.   No se pudo Grabar la información. '
                    +'Tipo Documento: '+ @DOCUMENTO + '  '
                    +'Documento: '+ @TIPO + '  '
        RAISERROR (@strMsg,16,1);           


    END CATCH


END
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es declarando una variable y completándola antes de cada insert. Por ejemplo, al comienzo de tu código:

```
DECLARE @Operacion VARCHAR(255)
```

Y antes de cada insert:

```
 SELECT @Operacion = 'Insertar en ASIENTO_DE_DIARIO'
 -- ASIENTO_DE_DIARIO
    INSERT INTO ASIENTO_DE_DIARIO
    (ASIENTO,PAQUETE,TIPO_ASIENTO,FECHA,CONTABILIDAD,ORIGEN,CLASE_ASIENTO,
        TOTAL_DEBITO_LOC,TOTAL_DEBITO_DOL,TOTAL_CREDITO_LOC,TOTAL_CREDITO_DOL,
        ULTIMO_USUARIO,FECHA_ULT_MODIF,MARCADO,NOTAS,TOTAL_CONTROL_LOC,TOTAL_CONTROL_DOL,
        USUARIO_CREACION,FECHA_CREACION,DEPENDENCIA)
    SELECT 
    @ASIENTO, @PAQUETE, @TIPO_ASIENTO, @FECHA, @CONTABILIDAD, @ORIGEN, @CLASE_ASIENTO,
    @TOTAL_DEBITO_LOC, @TOTAL_DEBITO_DOL, @TOTAL_CREDITO_LOC, @TOTAL_CREDITO_DOL,
    @ULTIMO_USUARIO, @FECHA_ULT_MODIF, @MARCADO, @NOTAS_TEMP, @TOTAL_CONTROL_LOC, @TOTAL_CONTROL_DOL,
    @USUARIO_CREACION, @FECHA_CREACION, @DEPENDENCIA;
```

y por último en el bloque `CATCH()` agregamos la variable `@Operacion` al mensaje final:

```
SET @strMsg = 'CARGA_XML_PROVEEDORES. Se ha producido un error al ' + @Operacion + ' !.   No se pudo Grabar la información. '
                +'Tipo Documento: '+ @DOCUMENTO + '  '
                +'Documento: '+ @TIPO + '  '
    RAISERROR (@strMsg,16,1);
```

Otra forma, no se me ocurre, habría que investigar si es posible recuperar automáticamente el nombre de la tabla dónde ocurrió el error, cosa que dudo un poco que se pueda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal es que lo hagas con la función `ERROR_MESSAGE()` y hagas uso de ella dentro de tu bloque `CATCH`. Esa función retorna un `VARCHAR` con el detalle de la falla, incluso la información de los datos que estás insertando.

Además de también hacer uso de la función `ERROR_LINE()` que te va a mostrar en qué línea se ocasionó el problema, el número del error con `ERROR_NUMBER()` incluso el nombre del *Stored Procedure* donde ocurrió la falla usando `ERROR_PROCEDURE()`.

Suponiendo que almacenas los errores ocasionados en un log, el código quedaría algo así:

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    -- Todas las operaciones requeridas, INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT etc.
   COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    INSERT INTO LOG
    SELECT ERROR_NUMBER(),  -- Número de error
           ERROR_LINE(),    -- Número de línea
           ERROR_MESSAGE(), -- Mensaje de error
           ERROR_PROCEDURE() -- Nombre del SP donde se originó el error
           GETDATE()        -- Fecha y hora en que originó el error

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0      
    BEGIN      
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;      
    END 
END CATCH
```

Algo que noté, es que en caso de falla no haes el `ROLLBACK` de tu transacción y por lo tanto se quedaría "viva" bloqueando los objetos que están involucrados dentro de la misma.